# How do I search for lines in a file that only contain ASCII characters and then act on them?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, text-processing, language-support, regex

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
English words only
English and 日本語
日本語のみ
English words only
English and 日本語
日本語のみ
English words only
Also English words only
English and 日本語
日本語のみ
English words only
English and 日本語
日本語のみ
```

Note that in the middle there, there are two lines, `English words only` and `Also English words only`, one right after the other.

What I need to do is take those two lines, and combine into one line separated by a `/`, like this:

```
English words only
English and 日本語
日本語のみ
English words only
English and 日本語
日本語のみ
English words only / Also English words only
English and 日本語
日本語のみ
English words only
English and 日本語
日本語のみ
```

I've found that I can search for lines with ASCII characters with the following regular expression, `[[:ascii:]]`, and for non-ASCII with `[^[:ascii:]]`. However, I'm having a little trouble using regular expressions to find instances of *not* matching a condition, since what I need to search on are lines *without* non-ASCII characters.

I found [this question about "inverse matching"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406230/184108), but, the answers there are beyond me.

Then, of course, it's another problem to match lines based on their relationship to each other. Can I match these lines when they are one after the other? I'm not even sure that is possible.

Is there a way I can search for all lines with no non-ASCII characters, and then combine them, using LibreOffice, Gedit, or the command line?

Note that the file is thousands of lines long, and also I am not sure, but it *might* be possible that there could be occurrences of English only lines that are in groups of 3 or 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you can use `sed` to do this job, even though it doesn't know about the `[[:ascii:]]` character class. Instead of that, we can specify all ASCII characters with a range of [escape sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Escapes) `[\d0-\d127]`, as long as we use the `C` or `POSIX` locales.

Here's a command that should be reliable:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -r ':a;N;s|^([\d0-\d127]+)\n([\d0-\d127]+)$|\1 / \2|;ta' file
```

#### Notes

- `LC_ALL=C` Use `C` locale settings only for this command (otherwise you get an error)
- `-r` Use extended regex to make the command more readable (we need fewer backslashes) (GNU `sed` also recognises `-E` with the same meaning).
- `:a` Label - loop starts here
- `;` Separates commands, like in the shell
- `N` Read the next line into the pattern space, so we can replace `\n`
- `s|old|new|` Replace `old` with `new`
- `^([\d0-\d127])\n([\d0-\d127]+)$` - match two lines with only ASCII and capture the first line in `\1` and the second line in `\2`. `^` is start of line, `\n` is a newline, and `$` is end of line, so `^line 1\nline 2$` tests the whole of `line 1` and `line 2`.
- `\1 / \2` The first and second lines, separated by  `/`  instead of a newline.
- `ta` - If the last search-and-replace command succeeded, execute the loop again. This allows us to process all the lines of the file, handling any instances where there are more than two all-ASCII lines together.

---

***Many thanks to [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) for [showing me how to use escape sequences to match ASCII characters](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44236309#44236309).***

Comment: Thank you for this command, it worked like a charm. Just an additional note for newbies like myself, one has to add `> outputfile.txt` at the end of the command (after where it says `file` in the command above, which is the input file) so that the results will actually get saved in a file.

Answer (score 4):

If you want *whole lines* consisting only of ASCII characters you need to anchor your pattern to the start and end of line e.g. with `grep`

```
$ grep -P '^[[:ascii:]]*$' file
English words only
English words only
English words only
Also English words only
English words only
```

Some tools provide a whole-line flag such as grep's `-x` or `--line-regexp`:

> ```
>    -x, --line-regexp
>           Select  only  those  matches  that exactly match the whole line.
>           For a regular expression pattern, this  is  like  parenthesizing
>           the pattern and then surrounding it with ^ and $.
> ```

allowing you to use:

```
$ grep -Px '[[:ascii:]]*' file
English words only
English words only
English words only
Also English words only
English words only
```

---

*Multiline* matching adds a whole other layer of complexity, since many of the common command line text processing utilities are line based. You can force `grep` to slurp a whole file using the `-Z` flag however there are tools such as `pcregrep` or `perl` itself are probably more appropriate at that point.

The *next* issue you need to solve is how to interpret the concepts "start of line" and "end of line" in the context of a multiline match. Some tools  provide flags for that, as described in [Regex Tutorial: Anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html): `perl` is one of these, which provides a `/m` modifier. You still need to slurp the file by unsetting the default record separator (done here using `-0777`); for example

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's{^([[:ascii:]]+)\n([[:ascii:]]+)$}{$1 / $2}mg' file
English words only
English and 日本語
日本語のみ
English words only
English and 日本語
日本語のみ
English words only / Also English words only
English and 日本語
日本語のみ
English words only
English and 日本語
日本語のみ
```