# How do I make a conditional search and replace that will add a line between two lines with different match criteria?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a text file many thousands of lines long with ASCII and non-ACII characters. It is *supposed* to follow a pattern of

```
First line: only non-ASCII characters
Second line: only non-ASCII characters
Third line: only ASCII characters
Fourth line: mix of ASCII and non-ASCII characters
```

Unfortunately, the reality is that it looks something like the following example, where in the middle it is missing the line that mixes ASCII and non-ASCII characters:

```
日本語のみ
日本語のみ
English words only
English and 日本語
日本語のみ
日本語のみ
English words only
日本語のみ
日本語のみ
English words only
English and 日本語
```

Fortunately, as far as I can tell, it is *only* the line that mixes ASCII and non-ASCII characters that is sometimes absent. Meaning that what should be groups of 4 lines are sometimes groups of only 3.

To fix the file, I need to:

1. Search for every line with *only* ASCII characters.
2. Test the line following to see if it contains *only* non-ASCII.
3. If so, insert a placeholder line following the ASCII only line.

The result should be:

```
日本語のみ
日本語のみ
English words only
English and 日本語
日本語のみ
日本語のみ
English words only
+Aあ+
日本語のみ
日本語のみ
English words only
English and 日本語
```

(I chose to make the placeholder `+Aあ+` so that it will conform to the mix of ASCII and non-ASCII as the lines it is standing in for.)

I've found I can use sed to insert new lines sed -e "/this is existing text/a\'this is a new line'" < file.text. And I've learned I can search for ASCII characters with sed using `LC_ALL=C` and `[\d0-\d127]`.

However, I'm unclear on how to make a conditional separate from the search. I mean, I could insert a line after every instance of ASCII only characters, but how do I make a search that inserts a line when an all ASCII line is found *and* the next line is only non-ASCII?

Please note that I am not particular about using sed. If an answer can be provided using Gedit, LibreOffice, or any command line operation, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your recent questions it sounds like you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Here's a sed solution based on @Zanna's answer to your previous question [How do I search for lines in a file that only contain ASCII characters and then act on them?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028473/178692)

```
$ LC_ALL=C sed -E '/^[\d0-\d127]+$/ {$!N; s/\n[^\d0-\d127]+$/\n+Aあ+&/;}' file
日本語のみ
日本語のみ
English words only
English and 日本語
日本語のみ
日本語のみ
English words only
+Aあ+
日本語のみ
日本語のみ
English words only
English and 日本語
```

Comment: Thank you for this help. Sometimes one doesn't know all the problems one will face until one takes a few steps into the task. Even after applying this, I still had to make many manual edits for exceptions and further search and replace tricks for conditions that had not been previously visible. Just the way it goes sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
awk '1; ! /^[\x01-\x7F]*$/ {next} {getline} !/[\x01-\x7F]/ {print "+Aあ+"} 1'
```

1. Print the input line unconditionally - `1` is a true condition, and the default action in that case is to print.
2. Then, if it isn't (`!`) entirely ASCII (`/^[\x01-\x7F]*$/`), skip processing more rules (proceeding to the next line, but processing rules from 1).
3. If it is entirely ASCII, we get the next line `{getline}`, and if that doesn't `!` have any ASCII characters `/[\x01-\x7F]/` in it, print your placeholder.
4. Finally print the line we read using `getline`.

I'm assuming that your 日本語のみ lines don't have half-width spaces or punctuation (`. !` vs `。　！`).